# find all matches in a string from array .. and return matches

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I've an array of colours i.e. array("Purple","Yellow","Pink","White","Blue","Red","Black");

I want to search a string for example "Black Ford Mondeo" and return an array of all matching colours from that string, in this case it would just contain Black

Any suggestions ?

Comment: explode + array_intersect

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), giving it an array reference to fill up with the matching colors.

```php
$colors = ["Purple","Yellow","Pink","White","Blue","Red","Black"];
$regexp = '/' . implode('|', $colors) . '/';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all($regexp, 'Black Ford Mondeo', $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```